# How do I apply SSL if my application (.NET Core) is running inside docker container?

Tags: docker, ssl, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

I have web application running inside a docker container on a digitalocean droplet. I've successfully generated the `.crt` files using `sslforfree.com`

But I'm confused where am I suppose to put the cert? My container is running using these command.

`docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 myrepo/mywebsite`

Comment: Include the certs in the container by `COPY` or `ADD`ing them in your dockerfile or bind mount them with `docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/on/container`

Comment: @Tim: which folder am I suppose to put it inside the docker container? I guess I can just use `docker cp` and copy the file manually inside the docker container.

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with docker. Use the same method as you would use when the application is running outside the container.

Comment: You can put the certificate file in your application folder, and which will be packaged into dokcer with your application program.  Here is a post https://carlos.mendible.com/2016/11/06/step-by-step-expose-asp-net-core-over-https-with-docker/, maybe you can try to follow it.